# Is there a way to use primary key as index when getting results using Eloquent of Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Let say I got a table in MySQL database like this, with id the primary key.

```
--------------------
|id | name | score |
--------------------
 1    Alice   77
--------------------
 2    Bob     89
--------------------
 3    Charlie 95
```

When using laravel eloquent to get the data from the table,

```
$result = TestingTable::get()->toArray();
return $result;
```

The return results is something like this:

```
{
   0: {
      id: 1,
      name: Alice,
      score: 77,
   },
   1: {
      id: 2,
      name: Bob,
      score: 89,
   },
   2: {
      id: 3,
      name: Charlie,
      score: 95,
   }
}
```

Is there a function so that the return array will be like:

```
{
   1: {
      name: Alice,
      score: 77,
   },
   2: {
      name: Bob,
      score: 89,
   },
   3: {
      name: Charlie,
      score: 95,
   }
}
```

In other words, do I have a way to make the primary key as the index of the return array?

I know I can get what I want by looping through the data and build my own array. I know I can write my own function and call it when I want. I just want to know if there are pre-built function in Laravel or PHP before writing one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `keyBy()` for that:

```
$result = TestingTable::get()->keyBy('id')->toArray();
```

Comment: Just to add that the return result is not completely like what I stated in the question. The id is used as the index but it is also retained in the array. Yet that is good enough for me and therefore I accept that as a correct answer.

Comment: That's true. If you want to hide it you can do that using the `$hidden` attribute in your model

Comment: You can still keyBy if the column is hidden?

Comment: Yes I think so... the hidden only comes in play when converting to an array and that happens after keyBy in your case